# Problem with Plot Callout LabelStyle Opacity

Tags: plotting, labeling, opacity

I am having problems with setting the opacity of callout labels when plotting. Strangely, it only seems to work when the text color is red.  In the following example, the odd labels should be 0.2 opacity, but as you can see it only works for red.

```
Plot[{
  Callout[Sin[x], "Boo", Above, LabelStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.2]}],
  Callout[Sin[x - 0.2], "Boo", Above, 
   LabelStyle -> {Red, Opacity[1.0]}],
  Callout[Sin[x - 0.4], "Boo", Above, 
   LabelStyle -> {Black, Opacity[0.2]}],
  Callout[Sin[x - 0.6], "Boo", Above, 
   LabelStyle -> {Black, Opacity[1.0]}],
  Callout[Sin[x - 0.8], "Boo", Above, 
   LabelStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.2]}],
  Callout[Sin[x - 1.0], "Boo", Above, 
   LabelStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[1.0]}],
  }, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is a bug.  When you look at `FullForm` of output you can see `List[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Opacity[0.2`]]` for red color and  `List[RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Opacity[0.2], Opacity[1]]` for blue color. For some reason Mathematica appends `Opacity[1]` after `Opacity[0.2]` which overrides the previous opacity setting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround for the bug:

```
Plot[{Callout[Sin[x], "Boo", Above, 
    LabelStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.2]}], 
   Callout[Sin[x - 0.2], "Boo", Above, 
    LabelStyle -> {Red, Opacity[1.0]}], 
   Callout[Sin[x - 0.4], "Boo", Above, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Opacity[0.2]}], 
   Callout[Sin[x - 0.6], "Boo", Above, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Opacity[1.0]}], 
   Callout[Sin[x - 0.8], "Boo", Above, 
    LabelStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.2]}], 
   Callout[Sin[x - 1.0], "Boo", Above, 
    LabelStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[1.0]}]}, {x, 0, 
   Pi}] /. {PatternSequence[x__, Opacity[y_], Opacity[1]]} -> {x, 
   Opacity[y]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me (v. 11.3, MacOS):

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I'm on v13.1.0.0, MacOS.

Comment: Same problem on Windows 13.1

Comment: it is not working only for some colors. If we replace Blue/Black with Orange it works. STRANG!